# Cannot import autobahn lib to Android intellij idea project

Tags: android, intellij-idea, autobahn, intellij-14

I want to import and use the websocket library autobahn in my project so I can use to test my server socket connection. I just confused what and where to import.

Comment: Which build system do you use? Maven, Gradle?

Comment: Im using gradle ..is that make differance ?